# How to access multiple variables of a function in a separate Python file without declaring global?

Tags: python

I have a two coding files

1. Main file for some data processing
2. User Interface to import 2 excel files (It will read and return the excel dataframe. At the same time, i want it to return the file name but I do not know how to access this variable)

This is the import_excel file:

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import filedialog

def getExcel1():
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    path=Path(import_file_path)
    df1 = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    return df1
```

My main file contains

```
import import_excel as UI

df1=UI.getExcel1() #excel dataframe
print(df1.path) #printing out the filename
```

I got this error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'path'
```

I want to access the variable "path" in getExcel1() function without declaring a Global variable nor mixing it into the excel dataframe.
Thank you for your help

Comment: You cannot access the local scope of a function after it has run (in any sane way). This has nothing to do with Python's import system. `df1` is a DataFrame, which you return from the function `getExcel1`. DataFrames have no attribute `path`. You could use `return path, df1`  in the function.

Comment: Have you considered that the DataFrame object has no attribute path? I just tried to reproduce your code with a random excel file on my side and I'll receive the same error. I also checked the pandas documentation and there seems to be no path attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this problem:

1. First is to simply return 2 values from your function:

```
def getExcel1():
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    path=Path(import_file_path)
    df1 = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    return df1,path
```

2. Create a function attribute

```
def getExcel1():
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    getExcel1.path=Path(import_file_path)
    df1 = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    return df1

df = getExcel1()
#You can then use it in print function
print(getExcel1().path)
```

Note that if you invoke the function more than one time then `print(getExcel1().path)` will print the path variable of the latest function invoked.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping. The first method returning more than 1 variable will change my df1 pandas Dataframe to a tuple which messes up my main code function. I can convert it to dataframe again but i was hoping for a more elegant solution.

The second method doesn't work with the same error "DataFrame" object has no attribute 'path'

Comment: Your approach #1 works well after extracting the dataframe and pathname to individual variables on the main function. That's good enough for me. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

As timgeb said there is no attribute path to a dataframe. You could return the path
by doing:

```
return df1, import_file_path
```

and in your main file do:

```
df1,df1_path = UI.getExcel1()
```